# Railsroutes, /john instead of /users/1 or /users/1-john or /users/john

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two apologies in advance.  One for trying to fight rails defaults, another for the example in the title, which I think sums up my question better than I can otherwise.  Any way to do what I want without having the world collapse on itself?  I got as far as putting a to_param in my model, but that doesn't quite go all the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't read it already, [this excellent guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) should provide you with all you need for custom routing.

Answer (score 0):

The full explanation is quite long. I wrote an article some months ago, focused on Authlogic.
You can easily adapt it to your needs.

[User profile permalinks with Ruby on Rails (and Authlogic)](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/08/user-profile-permalinks-with-ruby-on-rails-and-authlogic/).